# How to optionally show figure in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I would like to have code which optionally displays a figure which has been generated using matplotlib in a Jupyter notebook. The reason I want this is that the figures are saved to the drive and sometimes it would be nice to not have to show them in the notebook itself.

Furthermore, I would like it to possible for multiple plots to be created within a single cell with some shown and some not shown.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y1 = t
y2 = t**2
show_fig1 = True
show_fig2 = True

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1.plot(t,y1)
fig1.savefig('fig1.png')
print('Showing Figure 1:')
if show_fig1:
    plt.show()

fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax2.plot(t,y2)
fig2.savefig('fig2.png')
print('Showing Figure 2:')
if show_fig2:
    plt.show()

print('Done Showing Figures')
```

The above code does not work but is my best effort.

If `show_fig1=False` and `show_fig2=True` then fig1 ends up being displayed as soon as `plt.show()` is called in the `fig2` block of code.

If `show_fig1=True` and `show_fig2=False` then `fig1` shows up correctly but `fig2` still appears at the end of the cell (after 'Done Showing Figures' is printed).

If they are both false then both plots appear at the very end of the cell.

I have tried other combinations like using `fig1.show()` instead of `plt.show()` but this doesn't seem to work. I've tried various adjustments like using or not using `%matplotlib inline` or `ion()` and `ioff()`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this works for you:

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(-5, 5, 100)
y1 = t
y2 = t**2
show_fig1 = True
show_fig2 = True

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, y1)
plt.savefig('fig1.png')
if show_fig1:
    plt.show()
else:
    plt.close()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, y2)
plt.savefig('fig2.png')
if show_fig2:
    plt.show()
else:
    plt.close()

print('Done Showing Figures')
```

Comment: This does not answer my question. I would always like to create the plot, it should always be generated and saved (I've altered the code in the question to show that the figures should be saved) but only optionally displayed.